# Xcode: linking to C++ libs fails because of different architectures

Tags: xcode, architecture, linker, objective-c++

I am trying to develop an iOS app with Xcode in Objective-C++ (therefore with .m, .mm and .cpp files). The .cpp files use third party libraries (OpenCV).

The build fails at the linking, with warnings like this (which lead to undefined reference errors):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib,
file was built for unsupported file format
( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 )
which is not the architecture being linked (i386): 
/opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib
```

My arch is **i386**.

I can see in the build log that Xcode ran the following command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 ...
```

I don't know if it's related, but when I type `llvm-g++ --version` in a terminal, I get:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

What can I do to make everything build on the same architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled upon the exact same OpenCV library as the one I was using, but with the right architecture (i386). It was provided as a *framework*, inside [this Github repository](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial).

Now Xcode is able to finish the entire build process because everything was built in the same arch! :D

Comment: But it seemed like the implementation was not exactly the same as in the x86_64 OpenCV library that I got from MacPorts. For instance the function `imread` didn't work so I had to look into the Github repo to find out that they defined their own _image to matrix_ function.